# How to Make a Path Dynamically Based off System Variable in Python For Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, platform, browser-automation

So I am trying to make a if statement to figure out how to dynamically set the path for a variable to be used by selenium. The main thing is I want the statement to look to see if the driver is installed and then break if the driver is not installed based off of the `platform.system()` function from `platform` module. I have the following, but I am getting an invalid syntax issue. I have the paths working and installed on a windows and Linux system so I know they work.

```
import selenium
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
import os
import unittest
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import platform
import logging
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from datetime import date

# Definitions
# find_elements_by_name
# find_elements_by_xpath
# find_elements_by_link_text
# find_elements_by_partial_link_text
# find_elements_by_tag_name
# find_elements_by_class_name
# find_elements_by_css_selector

# System Variables
date = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
system = platform.system()
today = date.today()
username = getpass.getuser()

# URL Variables 
login_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/'
redirect_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/'
reports_scheduler_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/reportScheduler'
custom_reports_url = 'https://www.accuplacer.org/api/home.html#/customReports'

# WebDriver Path for System
if system = ('Windows'):
      browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
elif system = ('Linux'):
      broswer = webdriver.Chrome("~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_linux64")
elif system = ('Darwin'):
      browser = webdriver("~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_mac64")
else:
      print("Are you sure you have the Selenium Webdriver for Chrome installed in the correct path?")
      continue

# Parent URL
browser.get("https://www.accuplacer.org")
```

When I try to pull up the site in Linux or Windows I get the following syntax error:

```
  File "secret_collegeboard_tsi_export.py", line 56
    if system = ('Windows'):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Use `==` for checking value equality. `=` is used for assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
if system == ('Windows'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
elif system == ('Linux'):
    broswer = webdriver.Chrome("~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_linux64")
elif system == ('Darwin'):
    browser = webdriver("~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_mac64")
```

= is the assign operator
== is the comparison operator

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did. Sorry I forgot to check in on it.

Answer (score 0):

**=**  is used to assign value to a`variable`. For `equality` check of `string` use

```
if system is 'Windows':
      browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
```

**OR**

```
if system == 'Windows':
      browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had actually figured it pretty quickly. I used the following, which is similar to both @Muzzamil and @testfile mentions:

```
# WebDriver Path for System
if platform.system() == ('Windows'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
elif platform.system() == ('Linux'):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/rbarrett/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
elif platform.system() == ('Darwin'):
    browser = webdriver(executable_path='~/Drivers/Google/Chrome/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver')
else:
    print("Are you sure you have the Selenium Webdriver installed in the correct path?")
```